# CONNECT within Postgres SQL file

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a command for connecting to a database *within* an SQL file?

I want to create a database and then immediately begin populating it with tables and data.  All contained within a single `.sql` file.  I'm not aware of anything that replaces the `\c` shell command?

Example SQL file:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CREATE USER myusername WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myusername;
CONNECT TO mydb USER myusername; --<-- something like this?

CREATE TABLE administrator (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    admin_name character varying(150),
    password character varying(255),
    active boolean,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    email character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE administrator OWNER TO myusername;
```

CONNECT is the closest thing I've found in the documentation, but it's encountering syntax errors. I couldn't find a wrapper that specifies where the tables should go either?

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONNECT"`

Comment: have you tried pg_restore?

Comment: `\c` should work provided you use `psql` to run that SQL script

Comment: Yup!  I'm familiar with pg_restore, \c psql -U -d.  Let's say I don't have access to the shell at all.  Is there a way to do this within a .sql file?

Comment: `\c` is a psql command, not a shell command. You can use it inside .sql script

Comment: If your client does not have an equivalent to `psql`'s `\c`, then no, you cannot do that from inside the script.

Comment: Ya, \c doesn't work within the SQL file where I'm running it. Maybe there isn't a direct solution here though so thank you all for the answers!

Comment: In PostgreSQL you establish a connection to a specific database when setting up a session. CREATE DATABASE creates a new database, so you need to establish a new connection if you want to send SQL commands to this new database. This is different from MS SQL Server, where you always connect to the server, not a specific database, and can use the "use" command to send commands to any database of your server. There you can even use tables from several databases within a single SELECT statement by fully qualifying them. PostgreSQL regards databases as separate and closed entities.

Answer (score -1):

Add the below statement instead of `connect to db`

```
\c mydb;
```

The reorder statements of execution should be

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
\c mydb;
CREATE USER myusername WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myusername;

CREATE TABLE administrator (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    admin_name character varying(150),
    password character varying(255),
    active boolean,
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    email character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE administrator OWNER TO myusername;
```