# Making 'Create database' re-runnable in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using Dbeaver to run queries for my database (postgresql). I am running two queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE example_db;
```

and before this query, I am running drop if exists query:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS example_db;
```

But, I am getting this error:

> SQL Error [55006]: ERROR: cannot drop the currently open database

I know that I should disconnect the current database and connect to another database to run the drop query but I could not find any way to switch databases in postgresql.

I used \connect db_name but it didn't work because \connect command in an SQL script being executed in a context that does not recognize \connect as a valid command.

I researched use database but found out that it works in mysql but not in postgresql. I tried using "IF not exists" and then run ‘create database’ command but it also did not work out because create database cannot be run within a transaction block in postgresql.

In short, I couldn't find any way to connect to another database inside the script

What is the solution here?

Comment: Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because it's unknow what errors you have, and what script your run.  (and, please, do not comment on your own question, you better use [edit] for that!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Luuk for a polite explanation. I fixed my question and deleted my comment.

Comment: "In PostgreSQL you establish a connection to a specific database when setting up a session. CREATE DATABASE creates a new database, so you need to establish a new connection if you want to send SQL commands to this new database. This is different from MS SQL Server, where you always connect to the server, not a specific database, and can use the "use" command to send commands to any database of your server. There you can even use tables from several databases within a single SELECT statement by fully qualifying them. PostgreSQL regards databases as separate and closed entities.",

Comment: previous comment is a copy from:  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663974/connect-within-postgres-sql-file#comment94248837_53663974

Comment: To be clear in MySQL a `database` is an alias for `schema` per [MySQL Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/glossary.html#glos_schema). Therefore you are creating new schemas in MySQL from a single connection. You can do that in Postgres also.

Comment: and then "How to change to the new schema" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65886605/724039